# (CSS) How to Shorten CSS code

Tags: css

How do I shorten this code without compromising their function?

```
.taster a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.taster a:hover , a:active {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #000000;
}

.contact a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.contact a:hover , a:active {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #000000;
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could help me out with this one.

Comment: Did you check if it works the way you expect?

Comment: This question would probably be better suited for the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.

Comment: yeah I did. Currently, I'm shortening by CSS code, particularly this one. If I attach the matching elements to `.taster , .contact a:link , a:visited`, it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Join matching styles for different selectors with a `,`

```
.taster a:link, .contact a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.taster a:hover, .contact a:hover, a:active {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Or if you want it even smaller, try with [a minifier](http://cssminifier.com/).

Comment: `a:visited` and `a:active` are global, not part of the `.taster` or `.contact`

Comment: same as the original question :)

Comment: Minifier just remove spaces. Is there tool for your made it ?

Answer (score 2):

This is all:

```
.taster a:link, 
.taster a:visited,
.contact a:link, 
.contact a:visited {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.taster a:hover, 
.taster a:active,
.contact a:hover,
.contact a:active {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Note that this shares the original post's bug (`a:visited` is being targeted globally -- twice -- when OP probably means `.taster a:visited` and `.contact a:visited`; same with `a:active`)

Comment: @PaulRoub missed that, an edit will be made :) Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.taster a:link, .taster a:visited, .contact a:link, a:visited {
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.taster a:hover , .taster a:active, .contact a:hover , a:active {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #000000;
}
```

or you can add it different (or one more) class for example "link" (for the first) and "hover" (for the second)

```
.link a:hover , a:active {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #000000;
}    
.hover a:link, a:visited{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do it like ".link a:hover , a:active" ? Maybe he wants to target only the links inside a taster and contact class...

Comment: Right, it depends how it is done - if he is going to use it more than once, twice. For example building complex theme with some parts black and whites with two looks of links, I would use this instead - just writing my links or whatever and add to it correct css without any need to go to styles and add the particular element while coding the site. Because if there will be more classes that will start to be bit long and hard to change it.